# How do I install facets on windows, ruby 1.8.7, rails 2.3.8, I get hpricot error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hpricot, facet

When I try to install the facets gem from rubygems, I get this error:

```
Using facets (2.8.4)
Installing hpricot (0.8.3) with native extensions c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:483:in `build_
extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't provide enough details about your Ruby environment, but I will assume you're using [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org)

If that is the case, please install the Development Kit as documented in the wiki [here](http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit) which can be downloaded from our [downloads](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads) section.